# Get Environment Variable Kubernetes on Next.js App

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, next.js

I've been reading other questions about getting K8s environment variables to work in a Next.js app, but no accepted answer till now.

My app works fine using .env.local but it's getting an error (undefined) when deployed to K8s.

This is my next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  },
};
```

K8s environment:

[image: k8s environment]

Can anyone help me to get that environment var works on my next.js app?

Right now I do a simple trick, that is added ARG and ENV on dockerfile, then inject it when I build the docker image

Dockerfile:

```
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}
```

Comment: What's the error you see in Kubernetes?

Comment: @Rico actually it's not error, just undefined NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL

Comment: Does your pod crash or is it still running when you get that message?

Comment: @Rico my question is how to read environment variable that set on kubernetes from next.js app, i got undefined when try to read process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL from client

Comment: I'm asking to see if it's possible to debug when the pod is running

Answer (score 16):

You should add the `ENV_VARS` in a `.env.local` file. in form of a `configMap`. (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

In Kubernetes you create a `configMap` like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
name: env-local
data:
  .env: |-
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http:/your.domain.com/api
    API_URL=http://another.endpoint.com/serverSide
kind: ConfigMap
```

Then you mount that `configMap` as FILE into your deployment, it then is available at `app/.env.local`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: your-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: your-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: your/image:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: your-app
        ports:
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/.env.local
          name: env-local
          readOnly: true
          subPath: .env.local
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: .env
            path: .env.local
          name: env-local
        name: env-local
```

What also worked - for me at least - for **server side vars** was simply adding them as regular env vars in my `deployment`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: your-app
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your-app-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"

    const withSvgr = require('next-svgr');
    
    module.exports = {   
        // Will only be available on the server side
        serverRuntimeConfig: {
            API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        },
        // Will be available on both server and client
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
            NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        },
    };
```

Comment: You can split the last code snippet in two as it makes reference to different files (K8s manifest and Next file).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue and got it working with Docker while still respecting the 12 Factor App Rules, the TL;DR is you need to modify your `next.js.config` and your `_app.js` files with the following:

`next.js.config`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // remove private variables from processEnv
    processEnv: Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(process.env).filter(([key]) =>
        key.includes('NEXT_PUBLIC_')
      )
    ),
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

`_app.js`

```
import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

// Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
// every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
// perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
// be server-side rendered.

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps }
}

export default MyApp
```

To access the environment variables in any page or component simply add this:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const {
  publicRuntimeConfig: { processEnv },
} = getConfig();
```

Here’s an example of what component would look like:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const {
  publicRuntimeConfig: { processEnv },
} = getConfig();

const Header = () => {

  const {NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGE} = processEnv;
  
  return (
    <div>
      Hello, {NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGE}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

The real issue is the way the Dockerfile starts the app in order to load env vars we need to start it with `npm start`.

I wrote an article with my findings if you want to get the full details of why and how it works: https://benmarte.com/blog/nextjs-in-docker/

I also made a sample repo which can be used as a template: https://github.com/benmarte/nextjs-docker

I will make a PR this week to the with-docker repo.

Answer (score 3):

I spent whole day experimenting with the ways to throw my vars into next js app not exposing them in a repo. None of above mentioned clues did the job, same as official docs. I use GitLab CI/CD for building stage, and K8S deployments. Finally made it work like so:

1. Create Project variables in GitLab
2. in .gitlab-ci.yml reconstructed .env.local (since it's the only point you get vars from)

```
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - touch .env.local
    - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY='$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY'" | cat >> .env.local
    ...
    - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID='$NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID'" | cat >> .env.local
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes set the environment variables in runtime. But the `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL` is created in BUILD TIME, not in RUN TIME.
That means that env var should be in the .env file when you run the command `npm run build`. It's not possible to set up that env var in run time according to the documentation:

```
This inlining occurs at build time, so your various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is built.
```

[image]

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

What you can do is implement the `getServerSideProps` and return the value in the props.

Or you have another option more complex to achieve the configuration in runtime there is a workaround like this https://dev.to/akdevcraft/react-runtime-variables-49dc

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the definition of the environment variable from your dockerfile.
Then add the definition of the environment variable to your deployment(or pod or replicaset), for exemple:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue
      imagePullPolicy: Always
env:
  - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL
    value: ANY_VALUE
...
```

Comment: Yep! This is the one!